Is "the expenditure of somebody/something" idiomatic?
I know you can say "The expenditure on a product" or "The expenditure for a category (of products)", but how can I connect "the expenditure" to the subject who spends the money? Is it correct to say:

The expenditure of this company for this category...
This company has a great expenditure for this category.
This company's expenditure for this category...


Try the preposition by.

So none of the above work, and I have to say "The expenditure by this company for this category"?

No, (3) is fine too.

"The expenditure of this company for this category" is perfectly idiomatic, but may not be advised in some technical circles. In this context "great" does not mean "large". This is the original meaning (as in Great Britain) but in normal usage today "great" definitely carries a value judgement.

@timchessish a "great expenditure" sounds similar to "at great expense", which isn't uncommon, and means a "large expense", so it's unlikely anyone would interpret that as a value judgement.

@Sam - "at great expense" is natural and clearly means large expense. You're right that "great expenditure" in this case would be interpreted correctly, but only because that's all it could reasonably mean. It does introduce unnecessary cognitive strain and I would definitely take this as an indicator that the writer was a non-native speaker.
